# Extract conversations using regex

Tags: python, regex, text

I have text like this:

> [agent]:Welcome to ABC bank My name is Asif. How may I help you
>   [cust]:I got additional charge in my credit card, I will not be paying this, please remove it
>   [agent]:Okay can I place the call on hold
>   [cust]:This is very unresponsive behaviour on banks side

The conversations are not line seperated. I need to extract only what customer said and ignore what agent said for analyzing customer sentiment. Please help with this regex.

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think @MagicBeans meant to say "I've tried `\]:.*` but it doesn't work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

`\[cust\]:((?:(?!\[\w+\]:).)*)`

or

`(?s)\[cust\]:(.*?)(?=\[\w+\]:|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/RT2O4y/1

Benchmarks:

```
Regex1:   \[cust\]:((?:(?!\[\w+\]:).)*)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    1.37 s,   1372.69 ms,   1372693 µs
Matches per sec:   72,849


Regex2:   (?s)\[cust\]:(.*?)(?=\[\w+\]:|$)
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   2
Elapsed Time:    0.92 s,   918.17 ms,   918175 µs
Matches per sec:   108,911
```